# uploaded file isn't getting saved in under resources in webapps

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipart

I am getting the same problem here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProductInInventory(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, HttpServletRequest request) {
        productDao.addProduct(product);

        MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
        String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/  ");
        System.out.println("rootDirectory >>>"+rootDirectory);
        path =  Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" +product.getProductName()+"_"+product.getProductId());

        if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
            try{
                productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
                System.out.println("actual path>>>" +path.toString());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving faild.");
            }
            }
        return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
    }
```

now the file is getting saved at path >>

C:\Users\rajan\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MusicStore\WEB-INF\resources\images\

but uploaded file isn't showing in webapps/resources/imaged in package explorer in my ide.

Comment: I think you should store the images in an isolated location and dont modify the resources of your web-app in this case if you have some repository you are unsync it and its not a good practice

Comment: hi cralfaro your statement " if you have some repository you are unsync it" could you please elaborate it ??

Comment: Sure, if you store the images inside WEB-INF/resources it's inside the structure of your project, where you also have images, css, html,...then if you modifies that content with files uploaded by the user, those files are only stored in the server, and if you decide to migrate server or move to another container, you would notice all those images are not syncronized with your local repository, because you never commit them. The best its keep your war isolated, and save those images in some global path like "/home/rajan/app/images" or something generic for any server.

Comment: thanks @cralfaro its clear to me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you're running your project directly from eclipse. When you do so, this is the location where our `WAR` resides(inside your workspace). This path is used by eclipse. So in this case, `C:\Users\rajan\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MusicStore` is the context base path. That's why file is stored there. Try running tomcat from terminal and you'll get it at the desired location.

Comment: Hi Durlabh thanks, it worked, now is there a way to fix this thing in STS or eclipse, as i am following a course in udemy that uses Intellij Idea and implements the above code, however after coding the course says to change output directory in project structure > artifacts > output directory (i.e. which comes under java buildpath > source in case of eclipse as per my understanding) but even after making that change i am not getting the desired output.